# computational error in lmerTest even with ham-data

Tags: lmer

lmerTest did not return p-values of my own model; so I tried to reproduce the example from the manual -

```
m <- lmer(Informed.liking ~ Gender+Information+Product +(1|Consumer), data=ham)
# gives summary of lmer object. The same as of class merMod but with
# additional p-values calculated based on Satterthwates approximations

summary(m)
```

but even then get the message:

```
summary from lme4 is returned
some computational error has occurred in lmerTest
```

and no p-values!
What´s wrong?

Thx in advance!

Comment: can't reproduce with lmerTest 2.0-29, lme4 1.1-9 (development, but I'm guessing CRAN version 1.1-8 would be fine)